# Android: User accounts and data

Tags: android, mysql, database, user-accounts

Before I start, this is a very basic level question. I am not asking for a solution to a vague and complexed problem, I am simply asking for a pointer so that I waste less time reading up about the wrong methods.

I am developing a small app that does the following:

- User creates account/logs in
- User updates personal information
- User can search for other users of the app
- User can only see another user's details if they are 'friends' (similar to facebook)
- User remains logged in on their device (like cookies for websites)
- User can create an account using facebook or google credentials

Is the best way to approach this to use a MySQL database? If so, is there a particularly good tutorial to follow? I have experience writing android apps but have never dealt with multiple users or databases before. Also, how do you keep each member's data secure?

Please point me in the right direction, I apologise if this is considered too vague a question.

Comment: If you are aiming at developing this in android, you will be better off with `sqlite` . it's preferable to use in conjunction with android .